# GeForce 7800 GT Nouveau drivers?

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors, nouveau, gpu-driver

After wasting **a lot** of time trying to get Radeon HD2600 to work i gave up and got my hands on two Geforce 7800GT. So far trying to get things going with one GPU at a time, out of box LiveCD 14.04 wouldn't even boot, screen would freeze. After lot of research and trying few different things setting nomodeset in grub did the trick. Finally got a desktop but both monitors are in clone mode and it doesn't look like the second monitor is even recognized. I was hoping not to go with binary nvidia but looks like i might have to go that route. If i went with windows everything would be up and running a week ago, and here i'm fighting just to boot things up out of box on 5yr old GPUs

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G70 [GeForce 7800 GT] (rev a1)
```

---

```
$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display UNCLAIMED     
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: G70 [GeForce 7800 GT]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:fd000000-fdffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:fc000000-fcffffff ioport:bc00(size=128) memory:fe7e0000-fe7fffff
```

---

```
$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 1280 x 1024
default connected primary 1280x1024+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1280x1024       0.0* 
   1024x768        0.0  
   800x600         0.0  
   640x480         0.0
```

---

```
$ grep EE /var/log/Xorg.1.log 
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[   484.141] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[   484.141] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[   484.141] (EE) 
[   484.141] (EE) Backtrace:
[   484.141] (EE) 0: X (xorg_backtrace+0x48) [0x7f8d03923c78]
[   484.141] (EE) 1: X (0x7f8d0377b000+0x1ac969) [0x7f8d03927969]
[   484.141] (EE) 2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x7f8d02878000+0x10340) [0x7f8d02888340]
[   484.141] (EE) 
[   484.141] (EE) Segmentation fault at address 0x0
[   484.141] (EE) 
[   484.141] (EE) Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
[   484.141] (EE) 
[   484.141] (EE) 
[   484.141] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.1.log" for additional information.
[   484.141] (EE)
```

Comment: I think the error is because you disabled KMS so the nouveau kernel module is not working. Check the output of `dmesg`

Comment: Didn't see anything stand out in dmesg. Anything i should look at specifically?

Comment: I do not have an Nvidia card, but I would expect the Nouveau driver to log that it was disabled with nomodeset.

Answer (score 0):

```
/dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
```

This error message is because you disabled Kernel Mode Setting with `nomodeset`. Nouveau requires KMS to work correctly. From [Nouveau TroubleShooting](http://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/TroubleShooting/)

> **Xorg fails to start with "(EE) [drm] failed to open device"**
>
> Your DDX does not work with your current kernel and/or libdrm. There
>   are at least three possible reasons for this: the nouveau DRM kernel
>   module is not loaded, a version mismatch between the Nouveau DRM and
>   libdrm, **or KMS being disabled**.
>
> First check, that lsmod command lists nouveau. If not, do modprobe
>   nouveau to load the nouveau DRM kernel module, and check the kernel
>   log for possible errors.
>
> If the kernel module nouveau is loaded according to lsmod command, but
>   there are no kernel messages about nouveau at all, then most likely
>   Nouveau KMS is disabled. This prevents the driver to work at all.
>   Possible places to disable KMS are:
>
> - kernel command line with: nomodeset, drm.modeset=0, nouveau.modeset=0 or similar
> - modprobe.conf or modprobe.d/ adding the module options drm modeset=0 or nouveau modeset=0
> - initramfs carrying the above module options
>
> Check and remove all those that you may find, and retry.

Comment: So in order to even boot into LiveCD i need to have nomodeset set else i won't get a desktop on Geforce card, but if i do set it then i can't use nouveau drivers that i need for that card? That makes a lot of sense. Must resist just booting into windows where it just works

Comment: Even a fancy brand of Linux is still Linux, and you are lucky the GUI works at all with most graphics cards. Even with Ubuntu, if you don't enjoy tweaking when it comes to major pieces like video drivers then you have chosen the wrong hobby.